# Get thumbnail from webp image .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, image, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, webp

I have an uploade controller that can save image to file and get thumbnail image from the file uploaded.
it's working with .jpeg or .png but how can i get thumbnail image from webp extension and save it as .webp too.
i got error parameter is not valid

```
uploadImage(IFormFile file){
....
Stream filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
await file.CopyToAsync(filestream);
var myBitmap = Image.FromStream(filestream);  <----- error: parameter is not valid 

using (var myThumbnail = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(150, 150, () => false, IntPtr.Zero))
{
   //e.Graphics.DrawImage(myThumbnail, 150, 75);   // scale main image if thum is big 
   size like 300 * 300
   myThumbnail.Save(thumbFullPathName);
}
filestream.Close();
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ImageProcessor nuget package:

```
Install-Package System.Drawing.Common
Install-Package ImageProcessor
Install-Package ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP
```

and save method:

```
private void SaveAsThumbnail(IFormFile file, string path, string unicFileName)
    {
        string thumbFolder = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), rootDir, "thumb", path);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(thumbFolder);
        string thumbFullPathName = Path.Combine(thumbFolder, unicFileName);
        using (var webPFileStream = new FileStream(thumbFullPathName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: false))
            {
                imageFactory.Load(file.OpenReadStream());
                var thumb = imageFactory.Image.GetThumbnailImage(150, 150, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
                imageFactory.Format(new WebPFormat())
                            .Quality(90)
                            .Save(webPFileStream);
            }
            webPFileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

and ofcurse you can resize it by resize method:

```
ImageFactory.Resize...
```

I found solution from elmah.io web site:

[working with webp in .net core](https://blog.elmah.io/convert-images-to-webp-with-asp-net-core-better-than-png-jpg-files/)

---

also there is another neget package:

```
ImageProcessor.NetCore
ImageProcessorWebP.NetCore
```